# When is the kernel of the $(n-1)$-power map a proper subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

## What is my question?

Recently I have been trying to learn The Miller–Rabin test and get stuck in detail as I posted in the title.

Firstly I will introduce some notions:

$L_n=\{ \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^+_n : \alpha^{n-1}=1 \}$

$\mathbb{Z}^*_n=\{\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^+_n: \exists   \beta \in \mathbb{Z}^+_n\ \text{such that}\ \alpha \beta = 1\} $

The question is: if $n$ is an even composite, how to show that $L_n 
\subsetneq \mathbb{Z}^*_n$? (the operation is multiplication)

## **What is the motivation of the question?**

For $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, define $[a]_n$ to be
$\{x \in \mathbb{Z}:x \equiv a\mod n\}$ ;
$x \equiv a\mod n$ means $x-a$ is an integer mutiple of $n$.

Define $\mathbb{Z}_n$to be $\{[a]_n:a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Define $\mathbb{Z}^+_n$ to be the set of non-zero
elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$;$|\mathbb{Z}_n^+|=n-1$

Given a positive integer $n>1$,
I want to define a set $L_n \subseteq  \mathbb{Z}^+_n$,
such that:

1. If n is prime, then $L_n = \mathbb{Z}_n^∗$.
2. If n is even composite, $|L_n| ≤ c(n − 1)$ for some constant $c < 1$.

Now I want to prove that if we define $L_n$ as :
$$\{\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_n^+ : \alpha^{n-1}=1\}$$
then we are done.

## **Why abstract algebra is important in the question?**

In fact, two operations have been defined on the set $\mathbb{Z}_n$:
$$[a]_n + [b]_n := [a+b]_n$$
$$[a]_n * [b]_n := [a*b]_n$$
You can assume these two definitions are well-defined.Thus $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a ring(in fact, a communative ring with uity). Moreover,$\mathbb{Z}^*_n$ is an abelian group under the multiplication $*$.

If we define a group homomorphism $\theta: \mathbb{Z}^*_n \to \mathbb{Z}^*_n$
as $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^{n-1}$, **then $L_n$ is exactly the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$;** thus $L_n$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$.

## More about $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$

$\mathbb{Z}^*_n=\{ [a]_n:gcd(a,n)=1 \}$;$|\mathbb{Z}^*_n|=\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's phi function.

If $n$ is a prime, then
$$\mathbb{Z}^*_n=\{[a]_n:a=1,2,...n-1\}$$
which is a cyclic group of order $n-1$;thus, $L_n = \mathbb{Z}_n^∗$.

For even composite number $n$,
if we can prove that $L_n \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}^*_n$,
then by Lagrange Theorem,$|\mathbb{Z}^*_n|=t|L_n|$ for some integer $t>1$,
we can conclude that
$$|L_n|=\frac{1}{t}|\mathbb{Z}^*_n| \le \frac{1}{2}|\mathbb{Z}^*_n|\le \frac{1}{2}(n-1)$$

Comment: Is $\beta$ another integer?

Comment: Dear @EricToporek:  $\beta$  is some element in $\mathbb{Z}^+_n$ :)

Comment: You need to assume that $n>2$ for otherwise $L_n=\Bbb{Z}_n^*$ is the trivial group. Hint: Consider $\alpha\equiv-1$.

Comment: But, we most likely need to know a bit more about your background to help you study all the theory in this algorithm. Can you tell us how much abstract algebra you have seen? Also, arguably your question is still lacking sufficient context. Have you studied [the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for your suggestions. I have added some additional information :)

Comment: Much better. May be a bit overkill, but better this way :-). Did you try my hint?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen since n is even, $(-1)^{n-1}=-1$, -1 is not in $L_n$. But $gcd(-1,n)=1$, so $L_n$ is a proper subset! I think I understand!

Comment: Correct. You may consider posting that as an answer, if that settles the main question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider $[-1]_n$

Since $n$ is even, $(−1)^{n−1}=−1$, $-1$ is not in $L_n$.

But gcd(−1,n)=1, so $L_n$ is a proper subset

Thanks for the help of Jyrki Lahtonen :)